# How to do pagination in Vue.js table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a web app, frontend using Vue.js, backend using Django.
How could I do  pagination in my Vue.js table?
I have tried jQuery DataTable but it's pagination loads very slow, which could not meet user's requirements.

```
<div id="app">
            <form  ref="form" id="myform" method="post" action="/tag_course/">
                <table id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course Material Title</th>                  
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(row, index) in filteredRows" :key="`isbn-${index}`">
                        <td  v-html="highlightMatches(row.title)">{{ row.title }}</td>                 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
</div>
    
    
    <script>
    var book_rows = [{title: query_results_book[0].fields.title}]
    const app = new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data:() => ({
                    filter: '',
                    rows: book_rows
                }),   
             computed: {
                filteredRows() {
                    return this.rows.filter(row => {
                        const author = 
                 String(row.author).toString().toLowerCase();
                        const title = String(row.title).toLowerCase();
                        const searchTerm = this.filter.toLowerCase();
                        return title.includes(searchTerm) ||
                            author.includes(searchTerm);
                    });
                }
            },        
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Assuming a lot of data, it would be a better idea to manage pagination in the backend.

Check the docs about [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/).

Comment: it would be much better using a UI-Framework like Vuetify - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/